# Calculation of a list partly

Tags: r

I have a list of matrix, e.g. `L=list(M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10,M11,M12)`

I would like to use this calculation

> M=Reduce(`+`, L)/rowSums(sapply(L, rowSums))

For each 3 matrices instead of the entire list; as follow:

for (M1,M2,M3) , (M4,M5,M6),(M7,M8,M9), then (M10,M11,M12).

I have tried this for the first group

`M=Reduce(`+`, L[1:3]/rowSums(sapply(L[1:3], rowSums))`

it works but i want to automatize it to get the 4 results at the same time whitin a new list

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to do this on each 3 elements either create a grouping variable with `rep` or use `gl` to `split` the `list` and then apply the function

```
fRed <- function(x) Reduce(`+`, x)/rowSums(sapply(x, rowSums))
lapply(split(lst, as.integer(gl(length(lst), 3, length(lst)))), fRed)
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(M1 = matrix(c(1,4,2,5), 2, 2), M2 = matrix(c(2,6,3,7), 2, 2),
   M3 =  matrix(c(1,4,2,5), 2, 2), M4 = matrix(c(1,4,2,5), 2, 2),
   M5 = matrix(c(2,6,3,7), 2, 2), M6 =  matrix(c(1,4,2,5), 2, 2))
```